# 'May' and 'can' differences

Tags: differences, modal-verbs

What's the difference between **may** and **can** in the following context?

1- Our company has decided to organize a online quiz competition for students all over India on this Monday at 7:00 PM. Those who are interested **may/can** register their name online at [www.xyz.com](http://www.xyz.com) before Sunday.

Comment: In this particular example, there's essentially no difference.

Comment: Realistically, 'may' here can only have the deontic (for 'may', permissive) sense (you're allowed to). However, 'can' here may be synonymous (are allowed to) **_or_** have the epistemic/dynamic meaning (are able to).

Comment: *Those who are interested **may** register online. Or they may not.*

Comment: Thank you all. I have got an answer.

Comment: If registering online is a prerequisite then they **must** register.